# Turning off auto login

Tags: 12.04, login

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 and have removed the GUI essentially making it a server.  I have been trying to figure out how to turn off the auto login on the tty1 command line that it boots too.  The other consoles do not have auto login setup.

Comment: Are you using `mingetty` for autologin?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I do not ever recall seeing anything named mingetty installed.

Comment: How did you enabled it? do reverse

Comment: It was auto enabled from install.  That is why I can not figure it out.  Never changed any files for it

Comment: TTY1 is logging in as somebody? That's not normal. How did you remove the GUI?

Comment: It is logging in as root, which is the only user on the machine so far, and tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the files named `/etc/init/ttyX.conf` (where X can be 1 to 6) as follows:

For example `tty1` :

```
sudo nano /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

Comment this line:

```
exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

And append below line :

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Comment: 'exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1' is currently what is in that file

Comment: Are you sure root user has password?

Comment: Yes.  however to solve this I am going to create a new user that has limited access abilities.  I am planning on giving them the ability to adjust IP settings.